# Rails application template regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have been working on a template to generate Rails application with configured testing environment.

The template is working fine expect for this line:

```
gsub_file 'spec/rails_helper.rb', /\Aconfig.fixture_path.*\Z/,""
```

I wanted to remove the following line from rails_helper.rb:

```
config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
```

I tried the following solutions without result:

```
comment_lines 'spec/rails_helper.rb', /\Aconfig.fixture_path.*\Z/
comment_lines 'spec/rails_helper.rb', /\Aconfig.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}\/spec\/fixtures"/
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Why not just create a config file and use that value during configuration? Or use an actual template to generate the Ruby file? Either would be significantly less brittle, and easier to modify.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the indication. So to fix the problem I removed rails_helper.rb file and create one with my configuration. Well it works but I'll try later to read the configuration from an external file.